# ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql

Tenho este select

```
SELECT
   `works`.`grade_id` FROM `works`
   INNER JOIN `work_images` ON `work_images`.`work_id` = `works`.`id`
   INNER JOIN `work_students` ON `work_students`.`work_id` = `works`.`id`
   RIGHT OUTER JOIN qrcodes on qrcodes.code = works.teacher_qrcode
WHERE
  (
     works.school_id IS NOT NULL
     AND works.material_id > 0
     AND works.teacher_qrcode IS NOT NULL
     AND work_students.student_qrcode IS NOT NULL
  )
  AND (work_students.student_qrcode =
     ('2odclt6c','s4001d5j8','s4000p3sd','0413g8vsj',
     'i40008tia','2odco0dv','2odd12pn','0413gsqma','2odfkal3','0413a4i8u','2odg00n4',
     '04137plis','2odehfpg','2odg9qhn','2oddpe4k','s40020n0c','i400112td','04136t1ti',
     '0413agib3','0413a12o7'))
LIMIT 6
OFFSET 0
```

E recebo este erro ao executar:

> ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Onde está faltando a coluna ?

Comment: where should contain ?

Comment: agora está em portgues

Comment: Provavelmente o problema está aqui: Você está usando igual para comparar vários valores. Se quer saber se é um só de uma lista de vários, usa-se o IN: `work_students.student_qrcode IN( '2o...`

Comment: Dei uma editada na sua pergunta pro SQL caber na tela, fica mais fácil das pessoas lerem e identificarem outros problemas. Olhando assim por cima, me parece que o problema realmente é o `=` no lugar onde deveria ser o IN. A propósito, se é tudo AND, nem precisa dos `( )`.

Comment: Realmente era o = , valeu

Answer (score 2):

Basicamente o problema é que nesta parte, você está comparando um valor com um grupo, e o operador de igualdade só aceita um campo ou valor de cada lado:

```
work_students.student_qrcode = ('2odclt6c','s4001d5j8','s4000p3sd','0413g8vsj'...
```

No caso, para saber se um valor está em uma lista de valores, o operador adequado é o `IN`:

```
work_students.student_qrcode IN('2odclt6c','s4001d5j8','s4000p3sd','0413g8vsj'...
```

Aproveitando, segue a sua *query* já com a correção mencionada, e uma leve otimização nos `AND` (como é tudo `AND`, o agrupamento é desnecessário):

```
SELECT
   `works`.`grade_id` FROM `works`
   INNER JOIN `work_images` ON `work_images`.`work_id` = `works`.`id`
   INNER JOIN `work_students` ON `work_students`.`work_id` = `works`.`id`
   RIGHT OUTER JOIN qrcodes on qrcodes.code = works.teacher_qrcode
WHERE
   works.school_id IS NOT NULL
   AND works.material_id > 0
   AND works.teacher_qrcode IS NOT NULL
   AND work_students.student_qrcode IS NOT NULL
   AND work_students.student_qrcode IN(
      '2odclt6c', 's4001d5j8', 's4000p3sd', '0413g8vsj', 'i40008tia', '2odco0dv',
      '2odd12pn', '0413gsqma', '2odfkal3', '0413a4i8u', '2odg00n4', '04137plis',
      '2odehfpg', '2odg9qhn', '2oddpe4k', 's40020n0c', 'i400112td', '04136t1ti',
      '0413agib3','0413a12o7'
   )
LIMIT  6
OFFSET 0
```